# Automatic update description of already submited change in Perforce. p4 change -u [changelist]

Tags: python, perforce

So, we have to handle several changelists and change their descriptions.
P4V is not an option, and the command always open the notepad for manual input.

I imagine this is possible because it works in the P4V editor and there is even a console command for it as well.

I tried with the command line but always shows the notepad for input:

```
p4 change -u 123< p4 change -i 123 (yeah even this shows the notepad)
```

using P4Python didnt work either:

```
change=p.fetch_change(changelist) 
change._description = do_change(change._description)
p.run_change('-u',change)
#p.save_change(... this works only with un-submitted changelists
```

And I also tried plain Popen in Python but I got as stuck as using a batch file.
I imagine somebody already did something similar. Any hint very appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you tried:

```
p4 change -u 123< p4 change -i 123 (yeah even this shows the notepad)
```

The command to the left of `<` runs `p4 change -u 123`, and of course that spawns your editor since it was run without `-i`. (`p4 change -i`  reads from stdin.)  Note that `p4 help change` shows:

```
p4 change -i [-s] [-f | -u]
```

and that `p4 change -i` does not expect a change number (it instead obtains the change number from the change description supplied via `stdin`), but it does explicitly state that it may be combined with `-u`, so all you need is just:

```
p4 change -i -u < CHANGE_DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?  Is there something incorrect about this answer?  It's basically the same as what Sam posted (but omits the step of creating `CHANGE_DESCRIPTION`, since I assume that the person asking already has that).  Furthermore, my answer explains why the attempted solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea with combining "change -u" and "change -i", but here's the general sort of syntax you want:

```
p4 change -o 123 | (text manipulation) | p4 change -u -i
```

The "change -i" command reads the change form from stdin, so you need to have a change form for it to read; the easiest way is usually to start with "change -o" to get the current form, then use a simple script to modify it (often you can do this with a "sed" one-liner).  Since the "change -i" is what actually modifies the form on the server, that's the command that needs the "-u" on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both for the answers:

There is a solution in P4Python:

```
p4.fetch_change(changelist)
p4Change._description = 'my new description'
p4.input=p4Change
p4.run_change('-u', '-i')
```

The trick for me, that you both made me realize, is that you can pass to "change -u -i" an already submitted changelist. And I found how to pipe in p4python... now is a lot cleaner imho.
Thanks both again!